# Can Hilt Android allow different instances of a viewmodel in different activites?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

When using the same viewmodel class in two different activities using Hilt ,an error "binding with matching key exists" is thrown for the parameters of the viewmodel.

```
@HiltViewModel 
class ViewmodelA @Inject constructor(val paramA :TypeA)
{ //some other code }
```

The above is a snippet for the viewmodel class.

This view model is being reused in two other activities.

The error is thrown during compilation on paramA in the second activity, saying "binding with matching key exists".

This was possible in dagger2 using viewmodel factories. But it seems like Hilt isn't happy with this.

Hilt version used : 2.37

Can anyone help here? / Is there any workaround for this?

Exact error goes like this:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] (package_name).TypeA cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements (AppName)_GeneratedInjector,
A binding with matching key exists in component: (package_name)_HiltComponents.ViewModelC
      (package_name).TypeA is injected at
          (package_name). ViewmodelA(…, paramA, …)
      (package_name).ViewmodelA is injected at
          (package_name of another_Activity).viewModel
      (package_name of another_activity) is injected at……………..
```

Comment: Please post the full error message.  Which class cannot be provided without an `@Inject` constructor or `@Provides` method?  In which component does a binding with matching key exist?

Comment: @Nitrodon TypeA cannot be provided. The components are not explicitly specified as Hilt generates it. ViewModelA is already being injected at Activity1, but when the same class of Viewmodel is being used in Activity2 the above error is thrown at compile time. Have posted an error snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to inject `ViewmodelA` directly into the second activity.  This is an error for `@HiltViewModel` classes, since Android Jetpack ViewModels should be accessed through `ViewModelProvider`.

```kotlin
// don't do this
@Inject
lateinit var viewModel: ViewmodelA

// do this instead
val viewModel: ViewmodelA by viewModels()
```

You would normally get an error message telling you not to inject a `HiltViewModel` class directly.  However, in this case, `TypeA` is only provided in `ViewModelComponent`, and you are trying to create an instance of `ViewmodelA` in `ActivityComponent`.  Your view model's dependencies cannot be satisfied in `ActivityComponent`, so Dagger throws an error about that first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, this was the mistake. As I am trying to migrate from dagger to hilt, I missed to remove the inject.